# HA karaf cellar cluster

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I have three karaf nodes in one cellar group on my machine. First node (`lb_node`) is used as load_balancer and other two nodes (`1_node` and `2_node`) are used as service nodes (with deployed features). Both nodes have `/service` address available. I've installed `cellar-http-balancer` feature on cluster. Also, I have installed locally sample feature both on `1_node` and `2_node`.
Problem is that, when I start `1_node` and `2_node` their services are not properly registered in `lb_node`. `http-list` output from `lb_node`:

```
    ID  | Servlet                    | Servlet-Name    | State       | Alias               | Url
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-10 | Failed      | /features           | [/features/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-11 | Failed      | /jolokia            | [/jolokia/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-12 | Failed      | /gogo               | [/gogo/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-9  | Failed      | /instance           | [/instance/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-13 | Failed      | /services           | [/services/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-8  | Deployed    | /jolokia            | [/jolokia/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-14 | Failed      | /system/console/res | [/system/console/res/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-15 | Failed      | /system/console     | [/system/console/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-3  | Deployed    | /gogo               | [/gogo/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-2  | Deployed    | /instance           | [/instance/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-7  | Deployed    | /features           | [/features/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-6  | Deployed    | /services           | [/services/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-5  | Deployed    | /system/console     | [/system/console/*]
    103 | CellarBalancerProxyServlet | ServletModel-4  | Deployed    | /system/console/res | [/system/console/res/*]
```

As you can see only one node registered address. When I enter `lb_node` url in browser to check if feature from other nodes works, it does. But when I shutdown registered node, then `lb_node` won't act as proxy anymore. It throws `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

In tutorial https://karaf.apache.org/manual/cellar/latest-4/#_http_balancer there is case for only one node with service and one balancer, this is not my case.

Is there any way to achieve active/active cluster with http load balancing using karaf and cellar?

Comment: Can downvoter write why he did that?

Answer (score 0):

I put this as answer because I can't comment (no reputation), I'm not answering your question but it may help you.

I found [this](https://github.com/oconnormi/karaf-cellar-examples/tree/master/cellar-failover-proxy) github project that does what I think you are trying to achieve, I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately github project that you have provided is not a active/active setup - it's active/passive. It's not what I was looking for.